# How to pass data to ActivatedRoute data property other than using Resolver guard

Tags: angular

As written in Angular documentation, some parameters are available through an injected router service called the ActivatedRoute. On of them is data property.

I know that i can pass data to that property using Resolver guard but i would like to learn on another options like passing data using routerLink or router.navigate to the data property.

Sometimes, its not a right to pass the data using params, when you don't want the params to be part of the URL on the location bar.

What i'm trying to do actually is to pass parameter from router.navigate to CanDeactivate guard so it will act differently when the param is exists but i do not want it to be shown on the location bar and i can not use a property that belongs to the active component.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass data from a component to another when routing.

Furthermore, passing data like this must be declared in your routing, meaning it locks the data, so you can't change it.

Now for the answer, it highly depends on the type of data you want to pass.

For instance, if you request detail for an article, then you just pass the article ID in the URL.

If you want to share a configuration object, then you can use a service to share data from one component to another.

If you work with parent-child components, then you can use `@Input` and `@Host` to share data between them.

You should give us your purpose and some context if you want a correct answer, because there's no perfect answer or no best answer, only acceptable answers that suit cases.

Comment: i updated the question, What i'm trying to do actually is to pass parameter from router.navigate to CanDeactivate guard so it will act differently when the param is exists but i do not want it to be shown on the location bar and i can not use a property that belongs to the active component.

Comment: Well your guards are services, meaning they can be injected into other components : you could put a variable inside of that service, and inject the service into your components so that they can change the value of this variable.